# Variables in vba not correctly evaluated

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am getting this issue through all the subroutines in the module of a form. Very often, but not so systematically, when I use the content of a textbox (in my case always the same, and only as an integer variable), such Text.Value is not recognized in inline evaluation. It will work if I store it in a variable.
To give an example I have to change this:

```
If Text0.Value > DCount("field","table") Then
    MsgBox "wrong"
EndIf
```

Into this for it to work properly:

```
Dim RNum as Integer
Dim RMax as Integer
RNum = Text0.Value
RMax = DCount("field","table")
If RNum > RMax Then
    MsgBox "wrong"
EndIf
```

Aside from wishing to understand the issue, this is affecting also a subform where the critical field is the MasterLinkField for the subform. In this case, it happens sometimes that the number of the record shown in the subform is not the one reported in the textbox, but the previous one. To "update" it, I have to run an action on the form, like moving to a different record.
Just to mention, but this is not the source of the problem, the form is unbound (for which I have my reasons for having it like this) and navigation/save/read of the record from the table from/to the form is made by buttons/actions.

I hope anyone can help me clarifying this issue.
Thanks in advance,

A.

Comment: Could it be a difference in the (data)type of the underlying/bound field and the type of the field in the `DCount`? What if you use `CInt(Text0.Value)` instead? And what about null values? You could use `Nz(Text0.Value,0)` to set null values to `0`.

Comment: The issue is in the form, not in the record or in the process of saving/reading. It seems that somehow that access caches the value of the textbox and uses such cached number in the code, EVEN THOUGH PRINTING IT I GET THE CORRECT VALUE. So forcing to save the content of the textbox seems a way to "update" its value in the cache of the form.

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Access 64-bit? What is the patch level of your Access installation? Maybe you are missing some patches/service pack(s)?

Comment: A text box, as the name indicates, holds a Text value, a string. DCount on the other hand, returns a variant, most likely of long type. So, basically you complain that VBA seems unable to coerce the text value from the text box into something it can compare with the return of the DCount function. Since you already found the solution this is just to satisfy your curiosity. However, looking at the facts, the value from the text box should be converted to Long, and to ensure compatibility you might convert the result from DCount similarly.

Comment: I guess your argument can formally be discussed, but it's not the point. What I am trying to focus onto is the fact that there seems to be a lag between the content of a control in a form and its cached value, if there is one. Which can be experienced by some inline evaluation not working. Apart from my curiosity, the problem is to understand where this lag is originated to avoid it propagating in the content of subforms. Since I am not an expert of access+vba, I do not know the exact chain of refresh/repaint events and where this could be faulted by my code.

Comment: What if you use Me.Text0 , which forces access to use the current form object. .Value is not required as it is the default property. Is Text0 bound to the forms record source? Where are you running this code - which event are you using?

Comment: I will give it a try. No control is bound to the record. All actions are triggered by pressing buttons, so ToggleX_dblclick() subs in VBA. I noticed I have started getting this flaws in the code when I have defined some global variables in the form module, which are then initialized at the beginning or every action by calling an initialization sub

Comment: A textbox's Value property isn't updated properly until you leave the field.  If you need to check it as it's being changed, use the .Text property instead.

Comment: @Variatus  Your statements are perhaps valid for an unbound control (which is the case here), but to be complete... the Value field does not always return a text value, even for a TextBox.  For a bound control, the Value field returns a variant of the specific data type of the bound field.

Comment: @Minty  `Me.Text0` "forces" the current form in about the same way that `Text0.Value` forces uses of the Value property.  Similar to the default property, `Me` is automatically referenced in the Form module.  In other words, `Me.Text0` is equivalent to `Text0.Value` in the context above.  For that matter, `Text0` and `Me.Text0.Value` are also equivalent.

Comment: @Variatus  After testing an **unbound TextBox**, the **Value field can contain a Variant of a non-string type**.  Specifically, the value contains a specific datatype compatible with the specified Format property.  The text is converted/coerced into a specific type.  For a numeric format, it will likely return a Double value; for a date Format, a Date value.  The Text property will still be text, but Value will not always be Text.  I know this is not the main problem, but I'm working to get an overall accurate understanding.

Comment: @Aldo_U  fbueckert's comment likely contains the key to your problem, since there is a delay in the Value property being set.  Use the AfterUpdate event to detect when the Value property is updated. But also consider learning about the functions `VarType(), TypeName(), IsNumeric(), IsObject()`, etc.  If you suspect a problem with VBA itself, first do in-depth checking of all your variable types and understand the order of events on Access controls.  It is not the same as other languages and is not always intuitive.

Comment: the data type of the text box will take on by default the underlying table column it is bound to. If the text box is NOT bound, then the data type is determined by the format settings. Set the text box to a number format, and you not have to cast the text box into that intermediate variable to force the data type of the text box.